# How can I use Semaphore in this C code about multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I am solving the assignment problem about thread.
It's about sorting random lowercase characters. 
when it's sorted well, I print out O mark and or not, Print out X.
using 2 threads.

I need to write code using semaphore, but I do not know how to and where to write sempahore.

So once I wrote the code without semaphore.
I should add the Sempahore now. but i don't know what part to fix.

Could you help me?
Do i have to make one more function for semaphore?

It's my code in C.

Comment: One int_array, two threads:(

Comment: Why is there a nanosleep() in the sorting?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, then Can't I use semaphore? Could you explain more detail about it?

Comment: I just follow the example that my prof. gave us. He said We OUGHT to use semaphore, but i don't know where to insert it .

Comment: I don't understand anything your posted about semaphores.  They are a synchro object, supplied and managed by your OS, and served up to your uiser code by the pthreads library.  Semaphores only support two operations, post and wait, that are well documented.  Please explain more about what you want to do.

Comment: 'I just follow the example that my prof. gave us' well, go back to your prof and tell him/her that its code sucks.

Comment: .or err.. . just mention that there seem to be deviations from normal safe practices in regard to access to the array.

Comment: Then you mean is that I have no reason to use a semaphore ? and when I remove nanosleep(), the result is same?

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown that could be improved by one or more semaphores.  If your prof gave this as an example of something where semaphores could be useful, it is a spectacularly bad example.  If I ran a competition for code where semaphores would be useless, this would be a contender.

Comment: Then you said that you can't find the reason why i wrote nanosleep() ; function.

Comment: then If I erase this part. the result will be same?

Comment: Yes.  With the sleep, results will be very bad.  Without the sleep, results will be very bad.  Just give up with this code and go back to your prof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ThingyWotsit said, do go back to your professor.

For the semaphore, think of its concept like a gate.

- The aforementioned `sem_post()` will increase the semaphore's counter by 1.
- `sem_wait()` will permit a thread passage and decrement the counter by 1;
- however, if after a `sem_wait()` the counter reaches 0, any other `sem_wait()` will halt the thread, close the gate until `sem_post` is `> 1`.

I hope that aids you in your endeavor.